# Consuming JSON into django view

Tags: python, json, django, django-templates, django-views

I want to use the api I created using `django_rest_framework` in my API.I want to use the json generated in my views and templates. This is my json -

```
[
{
"url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/clubs/1/persons/",
"id": 1,
"club_name": "club1",
"persons": [
    1,
    2
]
},
{
"url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/clubs/2/persons/",
"id": 2,
"club_name": "club2",
"persons": [
    1,
    4
]
},
]
```

and I want to use it in my templates like so -

```
{% for c in club %}
  {{c.url}}{{c.club_name}}  
{% endfor %}
```

I tried the following view,getting unicode strings out separately but then `url` and `club_name` would be in different contexts -

```
def clubs(request):
  data = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/clubs/').json()
  count=0
  for i in data:
    count+=1
  g=[]
  identity=[]
  for j in range(count):
    g.append(data[j]['club_name'])
    identity.append(data[j]['url'])

  context = RequestContext(request, {
    'club_name': g,'count':count,'url':identity,
  }) 
  return render_to_response('imgui/clubs.html', context)
```

Is there any other way to do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `club` you need in your template is what you call `data` in your view:

```
def clubs(request):
    data = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/clubs/').json()

    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'club': data,
    })

    return render_to_response('imgui/genres.html', context)
```

---

Not relevant to the problem itself, but a few hints:

- This loop:

  ```
  count=0
  for i in data:
      count+=1
  ```

  is equivalent to: `count = len(data)`
- This loop:

  ```
  for j in range(count):
      g.append(data[j]['club_name'])
      identity.append(data[j]['url'])
  ```

  can be better written as:

  ```
  for c in data:
      g.append(c['club_name'])
      identity.append(c['url'])
  ```